# Is it possible to dynamically create equivalent of limits.h macros during compilation?

Tags: c, dynamic, portability, limits

Main reason for this is attempt to write perfectly portable C library. After a few weeks i ended up with constants, which are unfortunately not very flexible (using constants for defining another constants isn't possible).
Thx for any advice or critic.

Comment: Did you consider GNU Autotools ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  `<limits.h>` already exists for any conforming C implementation; how does `#include <limits.h>` not solve your problem?  And what do you mean by "using constants for defining another constants isn't possible"; I can think of several interpretations of that statement, none of which are true.  Please provide concrete examples.

Comment: I'm not sure if macros in `limits.h` are always defined, so i decided to not rely on em and create my own. By using constants in constants i mean i can't do something like this:    `const unsigned long BYTE_BIT_SIZE = __GET_BIT_SIZE((unsigned char)~0UL);    const unsigned long DWORD_BIT_SIZE = BYTE_BIT_SIZE * sizeof(long);` instead i have to call __GET_BIT_SIZE macro again, which is more than huge.

Comment: @Neko: Then you should read the C standard. The macros in `limits.h` are always defined; trying to be "more portable" by ignoring them and defining your own (with definitions that will probably be incorrect) is a misguided endeavor and will make your program **less portable**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask of is impossible. As stated before me, any standards compliant implementation of C will have `limits.h` correctly defined. If it's incorrect for whatever reason, blame the vendor of the compiler. Any "dynamic" discovery of the true limits wouldn't be possible at compile time, especially if you're cross compiling for an embedded system, and thus the target architecture might have smaller integers than the compiling system.

To dynamically discover the limits, you would have to do it at run-time by bit shifting, multiplying, or adding until an overflow is encountered, but then you have a variable in memory rather than a constant, which would be significantly slower. (This wouldn't be reliable anyways since different architectures use different bit-level representations, and arithmetic sometimes gets a bit funky around the limits especially with signed and abstract number representations such as floats)

Just use standard types and limits as found in `stdint.h` and `limits.h`, or try to avoid pushing the limits all together.

Comment: That's exactly right. limits and stdint are a part of the C standard library, which the compiler must have correctly defined and implemented. It's technically required for the compiler to emulate types that the architecture doesn't support, but not all implementations do. I've seen a few implementations of C that don't support floats, but then again, they weren't labeled as C standards compliant.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind: have you considered using stdint.h? Thanks to that your library will be portable across C99-compliant compilers.

Comment: Does it mean, it will be compiler dependant, also is it guaranteed that stdint.h macros will be always defined/defined correctly ?

Comment: @Neko: A C99 compiler will always have `stdint.h`, just as a C89/C90 compiler will always have `limits.h`.  It's there so you can write portable code.